# Amcharts - Force display of balloons

Tags: amcharts

I have troubles with an AmSerialChart trying to force display balloons on the graphs **without** having to over the chart.

Right now, I feed data to the chart when the user type a number into an input, draw the chart, showCursorAt() the specidied category... and that's it. I can't manage to force AmCharts to display the balloons before the user hover the charts.

Do you know if there is a reliable way of doing that ? I can see two possible solutions:
- a setting in AmCharts to do that
- fake a mouseover over the chart (ugly)

I didn't find anything in the AmCharts settings and I can't manage to trigger a mouseover event that works.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the only way to trigger the balloon without a mouseover is to use `showCursorAt`. If you need to see the values without hovering over the chart, consider setting the graph's [`labelText`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#labelText) instead and disable the balloon:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  // ...
  "graphs": [{
    // ...
    "labelText": "[[value]]",
    "showBalloon": false
  }],
  // ...
});
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/0607610525b24cf9dbbe32b2255a28b1)